# MVVMCross notify ViewModel of change in Model property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am new to the MVVM pattern and thus new to **MVVMCross**. But I can't seem to figure out how to **notify the ViewModel of changes to the model's properties**. Perhaps I am understanding the pattern wrong and using the wrong architecture ?

Here is my Model class:

```
 public class WallModel: MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _oc;

        public double oc
        {
            get { return _oc; }
            set 
            {
                _oc = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => oc);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my ViewModel I have the following property of the WallModel class:

```
private WallModel _wallModel = new WallModel();

        public WallModel wallModel
        {
            get { return _wallModel; }
            set 
            { 
                SetProperty(ref _wallModel, value);
            }
        }
```

I can retrieve data from the model just fine so the problem is not with the binding.

What is currently happening is that the `set` of the oc property in the model is firing but the ViewModels `set` is not being fired.

What I was hoping to happen is that the `RaisePropertyChanged(() => oc);` would cause the ViewModles `set` to fire but it does not.

What does `RaisePropertyChanged(() => oc);` do then ?
Am I misinterpreting the MVVM model and should I change my architecture?**
How can I get the desired behavior?

I have tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` manually but this to does not wprk

Comment: *What is currently happening is that the set of the oc property in the model is firing but the ViewModels set is not being fired.* and why it should? you are not changing `wallModel` in `ViewModel` ... Why you need this? binding should works fine ... If you need this then you should register for `INotifyPropertyChanged` change in `ViewModel` ... `_wallModel.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => { /* do whatever you want ... */ }`

Comment: The ViewModels needs to be notified as the updated Model needs to be passed to another model for processing.

Answer (score 0):

What `RaisePropertyChanged(() => oc);` does is notifying **only** the property oc of WallModel changed. Meanwhile, the WallModel on ViewModel still holds the same object of the WallModel so it assumes nothing changed.

Try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439841/mvvm-in-wpf-how-to-alert-viewmodel-of-changes-in-model-or-should-i) guide to getting it notified.